# Table design about sets of data collection elements

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relational-database

Let me know if you need additional information as this is my first post to the forums.

The design is for clinical studies. Easiest way to explain would be to give an example to a scenario which applies to all studies/protocols in some shape or form. Say I have:

- Study1, Study2, Study3
- Study1 has Protocol1, Protocol2, Protocol3
- Each protocol has "data collection" (set of forms, questions and sample collections, which can overlap across studies and/or protocols)
- All these data collections are scheduled to be completed in clinic visits.

I can build all the relationships between Study, Protocol and Questions similar to a questionnaire/survey design structure. However this is where it gets tricky with the protocol definitions and how to link protocols back to the data collection items, some examples are:

- Protocol1 has a form that needs to be filled every 3 months after enrollment to 24 months, then every 6 months.
- Protocol1 has a sample collection at 6month, 15month, 27month and then annually.
- Protocol1 has another sample collection which needs to happen at the age of 4, 5 and 6.
- Some data collection items are at the enrollment, some are every visit, etc..

What I want is to have a "To-do list" for that clinic visit for a specific patient based on all the relationships between study-protocol-datacollection but I am not sure how to define these conditional criteria for protocols at the back-end to be able to query? or am I trying to do something unrealistic?

**I am using SQL Server by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having set up similar schemas myself I would recommend you take the approach of generating all future schedule dates and storing these in a table linked to patient rather than try to calculate these "on the fly". I think this will save you a lot of headaches and difficult queries. For example you could have a table defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE PatientSchedule
(
     PatientId INT, /* foreign key into Patient table */
     ProtocolId INT, /* foreign key into Protocol table */
     StudyId INT,  /* foreign key into Study table */
     DataCollectionId INT, /* foreign key into DataCollection table */
     SampleCollectionId INT, /* Foreign key into sample table */
     ScheduleDate DATE
)
```

(you'll obviously need to adapt this based on your particular relationships but hopefully you get the idea).

This table can then be pre-populated for a particular patient when they enroll for a particular Study/Protocol inserting all scheduled dates upto whatever date is likely to be the realistic maximum in the future.

For a particular clinic visit the "To Do List" query should then be as simple as something like:

```
SELECT * FROM PatientSchedule
WHERE PatientId = ??
AND ScheduleDate = <clinic visit date>
```

If schedule dates are changed for any reason in the future it shouldn't be too difficult to update the PatientSchedule table.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but with this approach everything would be tied to scheduling of the patient rather than pre-defined to-do lists per study per protocol, which then can be assigned to appointments or is this really the only way to tackle this? Can I create this kind of meta-data outside of patient concept which patients would enroll to? I don't know maybe study scheduling (based on data collections) and actual patient scheduling can be separate?

Comment: Also once the intervals are set between protocols and data collection elements, linking that back to patient schedule/appointment is easy but how is the protocol-datacollection table is gonna look like with pre-populated dates? And when you add a new patient to the system, what are my reference tables with dates are gonna look like so that once I add the patient to a study, all the data elements will be set..I guess I am just confused..

Comment: I can't say I fully understand the problem. But you could define the frequency between DataCollections (for example) in a DataCollectionFrequency table having several rows containing 0, 3, 6, 12, 24, 36 as the monthly intervals between successive collections for a particular Data Collection. You could then use this table to generate the dates into the PatientSchedule table I describe above when a patient is "enrolled" into that Data Collection.

Comment: It may be that a particular Data Collection freqeuncy depends on the Protocol and/or Study it belongs to in which case also include the ProtocolId and/or StudyId into the DataCollectionFrequency table (and give it a better name perhaps!)

Comment: ...just to add - it's hard to give a definitive answer without seeing the Protocol/Study/Data Collection/Sample collection relationships but their definitions I think should specify frequency/intervals and these tied to specific dates when a patient enrols (the PatientSchedule table).

Comment: So let's go a little deeper: FormQuestion(FormQuestionId, FormId, QuestionId) which defines every possible form/question combination. Then we have StudyProtocol (StudyProtocolId, StudyId, ProtocolId) which defines the combinations again. Study-Protocol relationship together defines what questions to be asked and their frequency. Where do I define that? Have a completely separate table DataFrequency with IsMontly, IsYearly, Offset kinda structure and then combine DataFrequencyId with StudyProtocolId and FormQuestionId in another junction table?

Comment: and when patient "enrolls" to a StudyProtocol then you would know what is going to be collected and when? I was gonna try to invite you to a chat but apparently I don't have enough reputation :)

Comment: Yes what you are saying basically sounds good. Assuming "month" is lowest level of time granularity I would suggest defining everything in terms of months the DataFrequency table could then be (StudyProtocolId, MonthOffset) with a many-to-1 link to StudyProtocol table e.g. a particularly StudyProtocol could then multiple DataFrequency rows with MonthOffset values 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48 i.e. at enrolment then every 3 months in 1st year, every 6 months in 2nd year then every year. When a patient enrols generate the schedule dates applying these month offsets to the enrolment date.

Comment: Again thank you for your time, I was also thinking the lowest level of time granularity of all different protocols. Couple questions, for enrollment based intervals, if I go with monthly, then numbers are gonna be in the hundreds with the offsets. Is that acceptable? What is the best way to differentiate monthly, yearly (enrollment date based) and age intervals, age 2,4,6 (DOB related) and every visit to-do's. What kind of indicators is the way to go to switch between these intervals? Maybe a supertype/subtype?

Comment: because it is gonna switch between enrollment based/DOB based combined with every visit frequency. Any column/table structure that you can give as to how to differentiate these frequencies with indicators based on DOB or enrollment date on top of every visit to-do's.

Comment: Hundreds of offsets shouldn't be a problem - the table is quite narrow (high density of records per data page). Make sure there is an index on the StudyProtocolId column bceause this will be used in JOIn condition of queries. To handle the DOB basee frequencies I would add an extra column to the DataFrequency table so table is (StudyProtocolId INT, MonthsOffest INT, RelativeToDoB BIT). Set RelativeToDoB to 1 if offset is relative to DoB. When setting ScheduledDate for patient need to calculate date relative to enrolment date or patient DoB depending on this flag.

Comment: You may also want to include a RelativeToDoB column in the PatientSchedule table so the clinician can see from the To Do list if this is a DoB anniversary scheduled appointment or not.

Comment: Thank you for all your feedback. I might create new follow up questions but for now I need to spend some time on it and come up with a draft design first.

Comment: I did ask a follow up question if you want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/15578997/2188687